# Laravel Add/Append Base URL to Database Result

Tags: php, database, laravel, response

In my laravel app database, the resource are saved as link like this

```
/storages/photos/bla-bla.png
```

what is the best way, so I can append my app url to the result,

```
www.baseurl.example/storages/photos/bla-bla.png
```

it's because the backend and front end has difference base url
Thanks

Comment: Get the app url from your environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

IT can be achieved in two ways

1. While storing the images/files

```php
 $request->photo
    ->storeAs(
        'photos', 
        config('app.url'). $request->file('photo')->getClientOriginalName()
    );
```

2. While accessing (via an accessor)

```php
class Some extends Model
{
    public function getPhotoAttribute($value)
    {
        return config('app.url'). $value;
    }

    public function setPhotoAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['photo'] = str_replace(config('app.url'), '', $value);
    }
}
```

You need to set the correct value for APP_URL in the .env file